# typedef for template class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have a template class something like :

```
template< type T >
class temp {
   T val;
};
```

I pass the reference of this class object in another class.

```
template <type T>
struct def {
    typedef def<T> type;
};

class Test {
   public:
       void func(def<T>::type & obj);
};
```

I am trying to create a typedef alias and use it in the function parameter, but results in a error.
I cannot templatize the Test class.

Comment: If you want a member function to take a template argument, you need either the member function or the containg class to be template too. A typedef won't change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `func` member function would have to be a member function template. You would have to add a `typename` in the appropriate place, since you are dealing with a dependent name:

```
class Test {
   public:
       template <typename T>           // member function template
       void func(typename def<T>::type & obj);
       //        ^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: +1 lol, I can't believe we both overlooked the `typename` for 5 minutes, so focussed on the OP's `type` error. Anyway, since you're the first to fix it, I've deleted my answer